# When I join two objects with logic, the logic from one is lost

Tags: game-engine

### In Blender Game Engine (BGE):

I am new to the blender game engine.  I was making a small game of a ball moving and jumping.

Two Balls(Spheres) are the main objects. One is controlled by the keyboard  the other by joystick

[image]

I Was expecting that when the two spheres are joined together the controls will be added together also., so there will be **one** ball  controlled by both the keyboard **And** Joystick.  When I Join the balls I  get one control only.

Can anyone tell me how to join the two sphere without losing the logic on the other ball?

Comment: When you "*merge two spheres*" I assume you are pressing `Ctrl+J` which is the meshe join operator, which handles geometry data, that means it manages mesh shapes alone, nothing more. The object is still just the receiving one, so all other data remains the same as before.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know Blender does not support merging logic bricks. It can completely replace it via a copy command.

As mentioned by Duarte Farrajota Ramos merging meshes does not care logic bricks.

I think it is possible via Blender Python. But I do not know if anyone ever created such an add-on.

Comment: Monster, [code to copy sensors](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/89901/15543) in related question.